# smallest value issue in shell script

Tags: if-statement

I'm trying to find most negative value that are stored in array.
I used the following code

```
    small=99999.999
    for M in ${val[@]}
    do
            if [ "$M" \< "$small" ]
            then small="$M"
            fi
    done
```

Let's consider the values are 
0
0.5764
1.2934
0.8826
3.3143
2.8783
4.5771
0.549
2.4977
0.2294
1.0407
-0.0854
0.1819
1.911
0.5448
1.1276
0.2128
1.5406
-0.2361
-0.7184
-0.0082

The above code is producing smallest value as -0.0082 which is not the answer.

Can anybody pl let me know the fact?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings (lexicographical order), instead you can put your condition in double parenthesis (to perform a numeric comparison) `if((a < b)); then` or use `-lt` notation:

```
#!/bin/bash

for M in ${val[@]}
do
    if [ "$M" -lt "$small" ]
    then small="$M"
    fi
done
```

Try it out in bash:

```
if \[ 100 \< 2 \]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

it will output yes, but its false.

```
if ((100 < 2)); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

it will output no, which is true.

```
if \[ 100 -lt 2 \]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

it will also give you the correct answer.

**But bash only handles integer math**, so you can use `bc` in your condition:

```
if [ $(bc <<< "$M < $small") -eq 1 ]
```

Comment: I also checked with ""if [[ $M < $small ]]"" however this doesn't work. Is there any option other than using ""bc""?

Comment: you can use python